# How to know if an URL is valid And Also check it will be open or not in swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my Project I need to save a user given url. So I need to check if it's a valid URL and most importantly if it will be open in a `WKWebView`. My Problem: I can verify an url but can't make sure it will be open or not?

Here is my code :

```
 func canOpenURL(_ string: String?) -> Bool {
        guard let urlStr = string,
            let url = URL(string: urlStr)
            else { return false }

        if !UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) { return false }
        let regEx = "((https|http)://)((\\w|-)+)(([.]|[/])((\\w|-)+))+"
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", argumentArray:[regEx])
        return predicate.evaluate(with: urlStr)
    }
```

I used something like this:

```
 if canOpenURL(ckeckedURL) {
            print("URL Can Open")
        } else {
            print("Url cant Open")
        }
```

The Problem is: 
When I give `ckeckedURL = https://klsklaksalskalksalksalkslkas.com` it also shows me valid. I know it's a valid url but it will not open in WKWebView. Is there any way to check it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to know if the user entered an url to a 'responding' website..? If that's the case you can make a URLRequest and check if the statusCode is successful, like this:

```swift
guard let url = URL(string: "https://asdasdasd.com") else { fatalError() }

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, resp, err in

    guard let resp = resp as? HTTPURLResponse else { print("not a HTTP URL"); return }

    if (200..<300).contains(resp.statusCode){
        print("valid")
    }else{
        print("invalid")
    }

}.resume()
```

Keep in mind that the dataTask completion will run asynchronously, so you probably want to have a waiting / loading system while you check the url...